# Let $E_{n+1} = a_n E_n + b_n$ and $R_{n+1} = a_n R_n + c_n$. Find $E_n - R_n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have two algorithms whose error can be described by a recursion relation. Let

$E_{n+1} = a_n E_n + b_n$ and $R_{n+1} = a_n R_n + c_n$ the two recursive error terms.

I don't have a general solution to these recursions, but what I am really interested in is a general solution to $E_n - R_n$, or at least a bound $\|E_n - R_n \| < C?$.

Is there an approach to solve such recursions? I thought I could get some edge by having a joint $a_n$, term, but when I write the difference, I get the same recursion:

$E_{n+1} - R_{n+1} = a_n ( E_n - R_n) + (b_n -c_n)$

so it seems I don't gain anything. Is it really the case?

Comment: @metamorphy. Thanks. I know. The terms themselves are quite complicated. Do you maybe have a reference about solving linear recursions with non-constant coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $~F_n~$ denote $~E_n - R_n.$ 
Let $~G_n~$ denote $~b_n - c_n.$

So, you have that

- $E_{n+1} = a_nE_n + b_n.$
- $R_{n+1} = a_nR_n + c_n.$

This implies that

$$E_{n+1} - R_{n+1} = a_n~\left(E_n - R_n\right) + b_n - c_n \implies $$

$$F_{n+1} = a_nF_n + G_n.$$

Charting, you have that

- $F_2 = a_1F_1 + G_1.$
- $F_3 = a_2F_2 + G_2$ 
  $= a_2[a_1F_1 + G_1] + G_2$ 
  $= a_1a_2F1 + a_2G1 + G_2.$
- Similarly, $F_4$ 
  $= a_1a_2a_3F_1 + a_2a_3G_1 + a_3G_2 + G_3.$

---

From the above results, the pattern is clear.

$$F_{n+1} = \left(\prod_{i=1}^n a_i\right)F_1$$

$$+ \sum_{k=2}^n \left\{ ~  
\left(\prod_{i=k}^n a_i\right)G_{k-1}
 ~\right\}$$
$$+ G_n.$$